Infinite Set of Naturals in Forcing Extension
Just a random doubt that came up while talking to a friend. Assume we have some forcing $\mathbb P$ that behaves pretty nicely, so for example we can assume it doesn't collapse $\omega_1$, it doesn't collapse $\mathbb R$, and if we call $G$ a generic for $\mathbb P$ then $\mathcal P(\omega)^V\subseteq \mathcal P(\omega)^{V[G]}$.
Is this enough to prove the following statement? Given any infinite set $X\in \mathcal P(\omega)^{V[G]}$, is there some infinite $Y\subseteq X$ such that $Y\in V$ (so $Y\in \mathcal P(\omega)^V$)? To me, it feels like something that should be pretty obvious, since if every subset that lives in $V$ of some set $X$ is finite, then it feels like $X$ should be finite as well. But neither me nor my friend haven't come up with a convincing proof of why this is true, and probably the answer is "trivially true" or "trivially false" so I am hoping for some enlightenment.

There is a very general observation that for any infinite $x \subseteq \omega$, there is an infinite $x' \subseteq \omega$, such that any infinite $y \subseteq x'$ codes $x$ in a very simple way:
Let $s\colon [\omega]^{<\omega} \to \omega$ be some bijection. Then let $x' = \{ s(x \cap n) : n \in \omega \}$. Whenever $y \subseteq x'$ is infinite, then $\bigcup_{k \in y} s^{-1}(k) = x$.
So this really has nothing to do with the properties of $\mathbb{P}$. As soon as you add a new real, your property will fail.

great observation! thank you!

This is not true.  For a counterexample, consider the "single Cohen" forcing where $\mathbb{P}$ is the set of functions from a finite subset of $\omega$ to $\{ 0, 1 \}$, ordered by reverse inclusion, and let $\dot S := \{ (p, \check n) \mid n \in \operatorname{dom}(p) \land p(n) = 1 \}$ be the name for the new subset of $\omega$ being added.  Then it's straightforward to show $\dot S^G$ must be infinite.  However, if you have any $Y \in \mathcal{P}(S) \cap V$, then in particular there must be some $p\in G$ such that $p \Vdash \check Y \subseteq \dot S$.  But from here, it is straightforward to conclude that for each $n\in Y$, $n\in \operatorname{dom}(p)$ and $p(n) = 1$; since $\operatorname{dom}(p)$ is finite, that implies that $Y$ is finite.
Also, by standard arguments, $\mathbb{P}$ satisfies the countable chain condition, so this forcing doesn't collapse any cardinals.

That's not random real forcing, that's Cohen forcing.

Oh, I thought Cohen forcing was restricted to adding enough new subsets to change the cardinality of $P(\omega)$, whereas this is just adding one new subset (and then the ones that follow from combinations with previous sets, of course).

No. This is the "single Cohen real" forcing. Random real forcing uses positive-measure closed (or Borel) subsets of $\mathcal{P}(\omega)$.

Thank you Daniel, indeed I hadn’t thought of this easy counterexample. Anyway, now I am curious whether there could be a condition to add about $\mathbb P$ to get the desired property. Surely if it doesn’t change $\mathcal P(\omega)$ then it’s trivially true. But what if we add reals? Cohen forcing doesn’t work for your example, but random? Sacks?

@alvoi No, as per my more general answer.
